# "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined" in typescript error

Tags: node.js, typescript

im trying to import a class in typescript code, so i try private classA = new ClassA, but it not work, the result is undefined, here is my code

```
import JWT from "../Utils/JWT"
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'

class LoginController{

    private JWT = new JWT();
    
    public login(req:Request, res:Response){
        const payload:object = {
            id:1,
            account:'eulaoshi'
        } 

        console.log(this.JWT.createJWT(payload))
        
        res.json({
            token : "this.JWT.createJWT(payload)"
        })
    }
}
export default LoginController
```

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'

class JWT {

    private secretKey = "eulaProject"
     
    public createJWT(payload:object):string{
        return jwt.sign(payload, this.secretKey)
    }

    public verifyToken(token:string, secretKey:string){
        jwt.verify(token, secretKey, (err, decoded)=>{
            if(err){
                console.error(err)
            }else{
                console.log(decoded)
            }
        })
    }
}

export default JWT
```

in class "LoginController" get error, in "console.log(this.JWT.createJWT(payload))"

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'JWT')
at login (D:\myproject\BackEndWorkspace\back_end\src\Controllers\LoginController.ts:16:26)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\myproject\BackEndWorkspace\back_end\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (D:\myproject\BackEndWorkspace\back_end\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
at Route.dispatch (D:\myproject\BackEndWorkspace\back_end\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\myproject\BackEndWorkspace\back_end\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at D:\myproject\BackEndWorkspace\back_end\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
at Function.process_params (D:\myproject\BackEndWorkspace\back_end\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
at next (D:\myproject\BackEndWorkspace\back_end\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
at Function.handle (D:\myproject\BackEndWorkspace\back_end\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:175:3)
at router (D:\myproject\BackEndWorkspace\back_end\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)

how do i fix it, and what is the problem, please teach me

Comment: That's a JavaScript error, not a Typescript error. `this` is `undefined`.

Comment: You are exporting both classes, good. But did you `import` JWT in the first class?

PS: You can also use the shorthand `export default class JWT { ... }` (instead of splitting the class definition from the export)

Comment: @Christian yes, i import JWT Class in first class, and jabaa is right, "this" is undefined, but how can i fix it, i have no idea about it

Answer (score -1):

How is the login method/function called? It's possible it's called with the wrong scope.

Try with the following:

```js
import JWT from '../Utils/JWT'
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'

export default class LoginController {

    private JWT = new JWT();
    
    public readonly login = (req: Request, res: Response): void => {
        const payload = {
            id: 1,
            account: 'eulaoshi'
        } 

        res.json({ token : this.JWT.createJWT(payload) })
    };
}
```

A lambda function automatically stays attached to the currently defined scope.

If that fixes it, it's a similar case to this one: [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_matrix')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77892434/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-matrix)