# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_matrix')

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, foreach

I want to write my position of figures on chess board (checkers) from Node List of tiles. I define a 2-dimensional array and fill it with 0. And I can freely change the value, if I use `this._matrix[0][1] = 1;` right at the start of method. However, when it comes to changing it inside of a forEach array, I get this type of error.

[how it is supposed to finally be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auDtx.png)

**My code:**

```
class Game{
    _matrix = Array(8).fill().map(() => Array(8).fill(0));
    _board = document.querySelectorAll("div.container>div"); // all tiles

    constructor(blackTiles){
        this.blackTiles = blackTiles;
    }
    
    fillMatrix(){
        console.log(this._matrix[0][1]) // 0
        this._matrix[0][1] = 1 // no errors
        console.log(this._matrix[0][1]) // 1

        this._board.forEach(function(element, i){
            if(i < 8){
                if(element.classList.contains("infest")){ //tiles, that have figures, have class "infest"
                    try{
                        let row = i / 8;
                        let col = i % 8;
                        this._matrix[parseInt(row)][parseInt(col)] = 1; //error
                    } catch(Error) { console.error(Error); }
                }
                i++;
            }
        });

        return this._matrix;
    }
}
```

**Full error:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_matrix')
    at script.js:41:30
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Game.fillMatrix (script.js:35:21)
    at window.onload (script.js:102:22)
```

Comment: perhaps, wrong scope of `this` keyword inside the forEach callback, use arrow instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you correctly found, the problem is on that specific line.

That is because inside a function, (defined with `function(){}`), `this` refers to the function itself, not the containing context.

You have three options at this point.

1. Make and use a reference to `this` (old school :)):

```js
const _this = this;
list.forEach(function(){
    _this.something;
})
```

2. Bind the function to the current object:

```js
list.forEach((function(){
    this.something;
}).bind(this));
```

3. Use an arrow function; it will be bound to the caller automatically:

```js
list.forEach(() => {
    this.something;
});
```

4. Bonus point: if you are using classes, you could also have a private lambda property do that as well:

```
_handleSomething = () => {
    this.something;
}

list.forEach(this._handleSomething);
```

I'd go for option 3.

Option 4 is useful when your function is an event handler that you need to remove afterwards.